# Existence and uniqueness of the minimal polynomyal using the primary decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Using the primary decomposition theorem, prove that there exists $v \in V$ such that $m_{f, v}=m_{f}$. Next, prove that for every polynomial $p$ such that $p \mid m_{f}$ there exists a vector $w$ such that $m_{f, w}=p$.

I would love to write an attempt but I feel pretty lost, sorry. I'm not very familiar with the primary decomposition theorem and I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made an attempt, but it might be wrong:

Existence of $v \in V / m_f=m_{f,v}$:

- For any $v \in V, m_{f, v}$ divides $m_f$, since if $m_f(f)=0$, then $m_f(f)(v)=0 \ \forall \ v \in V$, implying that $m_{f, v}$, which annihilates $v$, must divide $m_f$.
- The primary decomposition theorem states that $V$ can be decomposed into a direct sum of invariant subspaces $V=\bigoplus_i^k V_i$, where each $V_i$ corresponds to a distinct irreducible factor of $m_f$, and the minimal polynomial of $f$ restricted to each $V_i$ is a power of that irreducible factor.
- Consider a basis $\left\{v_1, \dots, v_i, \dots, v_k\right\}$ for $V$ where each $v_i$ is chosen from each of the invariant subspaces $V_i$.   $m_f(f)$ is the minimal polynomial that annihilates every component $v_i$ in each invariant subspace, and thus, it must annihilate their sum $v$, so $v=\sum_i v_i$. Since $m_{f, v}$ divides $m_f$ and has the same annihilating effect on $v$, we conclude $m_{f, v}=m_f$.

Existence of $w$ for any $p | m_f$:

- Given a polynomial $p$ such that $p \mid m_f$, using the primary decomposition theorem, we decompose $V$ into a direct sum of invariant subspaces $V=\bigoplus_i V_i$ according to the irreducible factors of $m_f$.
- Since $p$ divides $m_f,\ p$ can be associated with a product of some of these irreducible factors or their powers that also appear in the decomposition of $V$. So we select $w$ from the direct sum of subspaces corresponding to the factors in $p$, ensuring that the minimal polynomial of $f$ with respect to $w$ is precisely $p$. This selection is possible because the minimal polynomial for each subspace $V_i$ is a factor (or power of a factor) of $m_f$, and by choosing $w$ appropriately from these subspaces, we can ensure $m_{f, w}=p$.

Am I missing something?

Attempt 2:

Existence of $v \in V / m_f=m_{f,v}$

- The primary decomposition theorem allows us to decompose $V$ into a direct sum of invariant subspaces $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k V_i$, where $k$ is the number of distinct invariant subspaces. For each invariant subspace $V_i$, we select a basis $\left\{v_{i 1}, \ldots, v_{i j_i}\right\}$. The index $i$ ranges from 1 to $k$, where $k$ is the number of distinct invariant subspaces into which $V$ is decomposed according to the primary decomposition theorem. The index $j$ for each $v_{ij}$​ ranges from 1 to $j_i$​, where $j_i$​ is the number of basis vectors in the i-th invariant subspace $V_i$​.
- We know that $m_{f, v_{i j}}$ divides $m_f$. Now, consider $v=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{j_i} a_{i j} v_{i j}$, where $a_{i j} \in F$ are scalars, not all zero, chosen such that $v$ is a non-trivial linear combination of the basis vectors across all subspaces. The minimal polynomial $m_{f, v}$ for this specific $v$ is the least common multiple (LCM) of the minimal polynomials $m_{f, v_{i j}}$ for the chosen basis vectors, which equals $m_f$, since $m_f$ is the minimal polynomial that annihilates the entire space $V$.
- Since $m_f(f)=0$ and $m_{f, v}$ is constructed to be $m_f$, $m_{f, v}(f)(w)=0$ for any $w \in V$. This follows because $m_f$ annihilates all basis vectors of $V$, and hence, by linearity, it annihilates any vector $w$ in $V$.

Existence of $w$ for any $p|m_f$

- Let $p \in F[x]$ be a polynomial such that $p$ divides $m_f$, and let $p=\prod_{j=1}^l q_j^{m_j}$ be its factorization, where $q_j$ are some of the irreducible factors of $m_f$ and $1 \leq m_j \leq n_j$ for each $j$.
- From the primary decomposition of $V$ associated with $m_f$, identify the subspaces $V_j^{\prime}$ corresponding to each $q_j^{m_j}$ in $p$. In each $V_j^{\prime}$, select a non-zero vector $w_j$ such that $q_j^{m_j}(f)\left(w_j\right)=0$ and $q_j^{m_j-1}(f)\left(w_j\right) \neq 0$, ensuring that the minimal polynomial for $w_j$ with respect to $\left.f\right|_{V_j^{\prime}}$ is exactly $q_j^{m_j}$.
- Define $w=\sum_{j=1}^l w_j$. Note that $p(f)(w)=0$ since $p(f)$ annihilates each $w_j$. Moreover, no polynomial $q$ with $\operatorname{deg}(q)<\operatorname{deg}(p)$ can satisfy $q(f)(w)=0$ because such a $q$ would fail to annihilate at least one $w_j$, due to the construction of $w_j$ with minimal polynomial $q_j^{m_j}$.
- Thus, we have constructed $w$ such that $m_{f, w}=p$.